# how to logout from both facebook and devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth

I have the following scenario:

- User logs in with Facebook connect (devise, omniauth)
- User starts browsing around the site
- User logs out from Facebook
- User can still browse around. <-- how can I prevent this from
  happening?

Update:

I followed gist.github.com/848721 but still i cannot solve

Comment: what have you done so far to implement this?

Comment: I followed https://gist.github.com/848721 but still i cannot solve

Comment: you should mention it in the question.

Comment: Ok. pls tell me what i can do for the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redirect user to facebook logout page with access token.

```
redirect_to "https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=#{YOUR_REDIRECT_URL}&access_token=#{USER_ACCESS_TOKEN}"
```

You can integrate with devise like that:

**controllers/application_controller.rb**

```
def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  "https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=#{YOUR_REDIRECT_URL}&access_token=#{USER_ACCESS_TOKEN}"
end
```

Comment: I tried this approach, but facebook won't redirect to my website, and faceboook lands on http://www.facebook.com/home.php and stay there, so whats wrong ?

Comment: Same problem.. did you find a solution?